# Chartjs is not showing charts in my Django project

Tags: javascript, django, charts, chart.js, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize data in my Django project using Chartjs. right now I'm only concerned with the visualize part and not the backend stuff but for some strange reason the charts refuses to display even though I took the boilerplate directly from the website just to display it before manipulating it.

```
<div id="chart_div" class="option-chart">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="648" height="495"></canvas>
          </div> 
          <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
            const myChart = {
                type : 'bar',
                data : {
                    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '# of Votes',
                        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                        backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                        ],
                        borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                        ],
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }]
                },
                options : {
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            </script>
```

As you can see from the code above. its boilerplate but I just cant get it to visualize.

Comment: This boilerplate https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/#creating-a-chart? You removed the part of the code that creates the `Chart` object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have not added the cdn [link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/)